# Simple regular expression 'select' x in string

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to select text in a string using a regular expresions but it i'm pulling my hear out. It's crazy.

I just want 'all' text whithin (" ")

```
$text = 'jow this should match ("text") and not (this) also not "this"';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

What $pattern should i be using?

Please help i'm going crazy here...

Thx,

Comment: It would help if you showed the `$pattern` you use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$text = 'jow this is some ("text") and some other text';
$pattern = '/\("([^"]*)"\)/';
preg_match($pattern, $text, $match);
echo $match[1];
```

Comment: Thx works but if i have this as $text - 'jow this is some ("text") and some ("other") text'.

i'm geting only 1 match, $match[2] is empty?

Comment: You should use [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/preg_match_all) and then $match[1] will be an array of all matched values.

Answer (score 1):

To work through things like this, i tend to go to an online regex tool or I'll write a small, academic program in the language I'm using to isolate the regular exprssion. For this one, I used http://regexpal.com/.

If you just want to match values that are surrounded by parens and double quotes, this should work for you

```
    \(".*?"\)
```

You need to "escape" (prepend with \ ) the parens in your regular expression because parens are meta characters in regex. The question mark after the .* makes it so the star (0 or more) quantifier isn't greedy. Without it, a phrase like

```
    this ("stuff") would not be ("captured") together
```

would match

```
    ("stuff") would not be ("captured")
```

instead of

```
    ("stuff")
```

and

```
    ("captured")
```

separately.

One thing I didn't get from your question is whether you are trying to match or capture the text between (".."). If you want to capture, you need to add another set of parens (this time unescaped) like this:

```
    \("(.*?)"\)
```

I'm not sure how php does it but other languages put this in a matching group object or into a magical variable like $1, $2, etc, for each captured item. You'll have to play around with that to get things straight, but this regular expression should get you what you need from my reading of your question.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
\"[a-z]*[A-Z]*[0-9]*\"
```

Comment: What you mean is `\"[a-zA-Z0-9]*\"`, but even then it would be missing the enclosing `(…)` literals.